# Can I start a chrome extension from the command line?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I have an extension that closes all tabs and bookmarks them in a new one, called [One Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall).

I want to automate this - how can I run a command that will run this extension?

I don't want a way to program the *features* myself - I want this to be applicable to any extension. I'm happy to modify and files in the `.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/*` folder.